# NSInvalidArgumentException with NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am attemting to use NSKeyedArchiver in order to archive data and for the life of me I can not understand the error being thrown. I am somewhat new to this but I have done it before and actually recycled quite a bit of the code, however, it won't work on this one. I hope someone can help.

This is the View Controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return groups.count
}

func loadSampleGroup() {
    let group1 = Group(name: "Spring Break", photo: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"), members: ["John","Joe", "Bob"], owed: 34.56, payLog: [])

    groups += [group1]
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "GroupTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? GroupTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Wrong kind of cell")
    }

    let group = groups[indexPath.row]
    cell.groupName.text = group.name
    var members = ""
    for name in group.members {
        members += (name+", ")
    }
    cell.membersLabel.text = members
    cell.groupPhotoIcon.image = group.photo
    return cell
}

@IBAction func unwindToGroupList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? NewGroupViewController, let group = sourceViewController.newGroup {
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: groups.count, section: 0)
        groups.append(group)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    saveGroups()
}

func saveGroups() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(groups, toFile: Group.ArchiveURL.path) //***Error is Thrown here***
    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Groups successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Groups failed to save...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }
}

private func loadGroups() -> [Group]? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Group.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Group]
}
```

This is the Group Class

```
class Group: NSObject {
var name: String
var photo: UIImage
var members: [String]
var owed: Double
var payLog: [String]


init(name: String, photo: UIImage, members: [String], owed: Double, payLog: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.members = members
    self.owed = owed
    self.payLog = payLog
}

//Persistent save data code
struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let members = "members"
    static let owed = "owed"
    static let payLog = "payLog"
}

//MARK: NSCoding
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
    aCoder.encode(members, forKey: PropertyKey.members)
    aCoder.encode(owed, forKey: PropertyKey.owed)
    aCoder.encode(payLog, forKey: PropertyKey.payLog)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
    let members = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.members)
    let owed = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: PropertyKey.owed)
    let payLog = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.payLog)

    self.init(name: name as! String, photo: photo!, members: members as! [String], owed: owed, payLog: payLog as! [String])
}

//MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("group")
```

}

Comment: Don't use these old Objective-C archiving tools. Use Swift Codable and related tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things you need to change

1.You forget to add `NSCoding`

```
class Group: NSObject, NSCoding{
```

2.Saving directly `UIImage` is not possible. Covert that into `Data` and save.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Bird.png")! 
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
```

3.As told by @rmaddy, please Don't use these old Objective-C archiving tools. Use Swift Codable and related tools

Comment: Thank you, this worked. This is for a class that is a bit out of date, but I will definitely read up on that subject because that absolutely sounds easier.